# upon automatic reloading page error is undefined index in php

Tags: php

I am beginner to php.. please help,,
I am passing data from one page to another using GET
I am reloading the page automatically using following code.

```
<?php require_once ("includes/sessions.php"); ?>
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "100000";
?>

 <?php include ("includes/connection.php"); ?>
 <?php 
   conferm_login();
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$usr = $_GET['usr']; 
$usr2='';
if($usr=='User1')
    $usr2='User2';
```

it works fine but after the automatic refresh the error i am getting is Unidentified index.pointing to variables i.e $user=$_GET['usr'] even in previous pages from where i send data. I also wrapped $user=$_GET['usr'] with if(isset($_GET['usr'])) but there will no output.

Comment: When refreshing a page, your get variables will not be retained. Therefore $_GET['usr'] will be empty after the first refresh.

Comment: And you are using way too much php opening/closing tags.

Comment: How do you trigger that script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
require_once ("includes/sessions.php");
include ("includes/connection.php");

$page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$sec = "100000";
   conferm_login();

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$usr = $_GET['usr']; 
$usr2='';
if($usr=='User1')
    $usr2='User2';
?>
```

Comment: Actually I have "include" ed this code in other code @Gumbo

Comment: So you are saying that this code is being included from another php file?

Comment: yes.. but its the home page after login.. I am passing data from login page